# Accessing a URL parameter outside the element in react-router-v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

**Issue:** I need to access a URL parameter **outside** the component in v6.

I know I can use the `useParams()` hook inside the component, But what if I needed to access a URL parameter **outside the component**?

This is how I used to do it in version 5:

```
// v5:
 
    <Route
        path = "/blog/:id" 
        render = {
            ({match:{params}}) => <Post item={ getPostById(params.id) } />
        }
    />
```

I am accessing the `:id` parameter outside the `< Post />` component.

**How can I write the previous code in v6?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `({match:{params}}) => <Post item={ getPostById(params.id) } />` you've effectively written an anonymous React component that consumes a `match` prop and renders your `Post` component.

If you've components that can't use the `useParams` hook then write a wrapper function component that reads the `id` param from the `useParams` hook and passes the `id` along.

```
const PostWithIdParam = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  return <Post item={getPostById(id)} />;
};

...

<Route
  path="/blog/:id" 
  element={<PostWithIdParam />}
/>
```